# UISearchBar at wrong position in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, ios11, xcode9

Adopting our code to iOS 11, i am struggling with the UISearchbar positioned in the UINavigationController.
I set up the SearchController/SearchBar like this:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"foo", @"bar"];
self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))
{
    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = YES;
    UISearchBar *searchbar = self.searchController.searchBar;
    [searchbar setSomeColors];
}
```

When using our default colors, things might look OK, but the space between SearchBar and ScopeButtons might be a bit too big:
[image: default layout]
Changing the backgroundColor of the searchbar reveals what is going wrong:
[image: different coloring reveals the problem]

So, the UISearchBar is placed a bit too high in its superview. Does anyone know, what causes this behaviour in iOS 11?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoa, i had no idea, this existed since iOS 5…

```
[self.searchController.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0, 8.0)];
```

See `UISearchBar.h`

```
@property(nonatomic) UIOffset searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

Comment: Please need more clarification.I dint get you.

Comment: There UISearchBar has a property called searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment which does what I needed. just set this property to your designated offset.